# Disk Encryption VS SQL TDE Encryption

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, sql-server

I am trying to understand what would be the benefit of using SQL TDE on top of underlying disk encryption.

My understanding is that disk encryption will prevent malicious users pulling out the disk from your server and being able to view anything unencrypted.

1) What benefit does SQL TDE give on top of Disk Encryption? For example, does it prevent anyone with access to the OS but not the SQL TDE copying the underlying DB data and viewing it?

2) Does SQL TDE have a dependency on strong User Access Management to protect the data within the database? Once a user is assigned access to the DB then they can view the data unencrypted?